# MySQL single column n-gram split and count

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, union, n-gram

Given a column of strings (passwords) in `MySQL` and given a value `N`, i'm looking for an sql-way to count the frequency of each n-gram (substrings of length n).

It's important to keep the code inside MySQL, cause in other environments I have, it will result with memory overflow.

The only working approach I found meanwhile is by assuming limited length of the string (legit assumption), `select` separately by extracting different locations substrings ,`union` and then `group by` and `count`, like this (for 9-grams out of 13 chars):

```
Select 
    nueve,
    count(*) as density,
    avg(location) as avgloc

From
    (select 
        mid(pass, 1, 9) as nueve, 1 as location
    from
        passdata
    where
        length(pass) >= 9 and length(pass) <= 13 UNION ALL select 
        mid(pass, 2, 9), 2 as location
    from
        passdata
    where
        length(pass) >= 10 and length(pass) <= 13 UNION ALL select 
        mid(pass, 3, 9), 3 as location
    from
        passdata
    where
        length(pass) >= 11 and length(pass) <= 13 UNION ALL select 
        mid(pass, 4, 9), 4 as location
    from
        passdata
    where
        length(pass) >= 12 and length(pass) <= 13 UNION ALL select 
        mid(pass, 5, 9), 5 as location
    from
        passdata
    where
        length(pass) = 13) as nueves
group by nueve
order by density DESC
```

The results are looking like this:

> ```
> nueve     density avgloc
> 123456789 1387    2.4564
> 234567890 193     2.7306
> 987654321 141     2.0355
> password1 111     1.7748
> 123123123 92      1.913
> liverpool 89      1.618
> 111111111 86      2.2791
> ```

where `nueve` is the 9-gram, `density` is the number of appearances, and `avgloc` is the mean starting location in the string

Any suggestions to improve the query? I'm doing the same for other n-grams too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table that contains all the numbers from 1 to the maximum length of passwords. You can then join with this to get the substring positions.

```
SELECT nueve, COUNT(*) AS density, AVG(location) as avgloc
FROM (
    SELECT MID(p.pass, n.num, @N) AS nueve, n.num AS location
    FROM passdata AS p
    JOIN numbers_table AS n ON LENGTH(p.pass) >= (@N + n.num - 1)
) AS x
GROUP BY nueve
ORDER BY density DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very clever! I think i would use it for word-counts too.

Comment: It's useful for any kind of numeric iteration, since SQL's only real way to do iteration is with joining.